# MA(q) model i.i.d assumption

Tags: time-series, moving-average

An MA(q) model is

$X_t = \mu + \sum_{j=1}^q{a_j \epsilon_{t-j}} + \epsilon_t$

where $\{\epsilon_t\} \sim WN(0, \sigma^2)$

Is it necessary for $\{\epsilon_t\}$ to be i.i.d white noise? My guess is that it is not necessary because one example of an MA(q) model is the k-period long return

$r_t[k] = r_t + r_{t-1} + r_{t-2} + ... + r_{t-k}$

In this case, $a_j = 1$, $\mu = 0$ and $r_t = \epsilon_t$. I don't think that the log return $\{r_t\}$ are i.i.d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different authors may have different definitions, but in the wide sense it is not necessary for the $\varepsilon_t$ in an MA(q) to be *independent*; they are simply required to be uncorrelated, with an identical, unspecified marginal distribution. Some authors do restrict the definition of MA(q) to have independent $\varepsilon_t$ and for each to have a normal distribution, however (to derive estimators, test statistic distributions, etc).

Concerning your last point: log-returns of financial assets are indeed frequently modeled as being uncorrelated, or even independent. Think of, for example, the Black-Scholes model. Depending on the goal for modelling, it may not be possible to build a better-performing model. Intuitively, you would not expect any easy-to-model dependence structure over time to exist; if there was, it would tend to be taken advantage of, and then disappear.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a model assumption, it is its definition.

Of course, you can define another model where the shocks are non-i.i.d., but you will have to give another name to that model; it will no longer be MA(q) as we know it.

Comment: If that is the case, why is the k-period log return a "classic" example of a MA(q) process? It doesn't seem likely that the log returns are independent.

Comment: @Student It is actually quite common to model log-returns on financial assets as being uncorrelated over time. It depends on the asset and the sampling frequency but it is not a bad assumption in general.

Comment: @ChrisHaug I understand that log-return is usually modeled as being uncorrelated over time. In fact, a white noise series by definition has to be uncorrelated over time. My only question is if it has to be independent. Uncorrelated does not imply independence.

Comment: @Student I am well-aware of those facts. Thank you for clarifying your question because it was not obvious at all that that was what you were asking.